# How much energy does it take to form a plasma channel with a laser?

Tags: energy, electricity, laser, plasma-physics

The usage is for something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolaser

I know that the laser is powered for an instant in which a plasma channel is formed for the electricity to flow through, but I couldn't find how much energy it'd take (assuming that it'd be measured in joules?).

Comment: Energy would, of course, be measured in Joules.

Comment: So a repeat of this then : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489597/207455

Comment: But aren't joules supposed to be watts per second? Are joules still relevant per instant? (say, 0.000...1, not sure about the exact duration)

Comment: it's only a repeat of the pre-edited version, it was basically 3 questions in one

Comment: Watts are joules per second. Joules are watt-seconds.